# Compare Two Columns (from two different worksheets) and show result of another column - excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have this scenario:

- Worksheet 1 with Column A only
- Worksheet 2 with Column A and B

I have to compare Column A (Worksheet 1) and Column A (Worksheet 2).

If a value in Column A (Worksheet 1) is existing in Column A (Worksheet 2), it must show the value in Column B (Worksheet 2).

Please help. I have been trying to do this. I can only compare the Column A of both worksheets but I cannot show the Column B.

Comment: What "value" are you looking to place in column B of Sheet2? If you are looking for duplicates, you just want to list the name in column B if it's found in Sheet1?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like you just need a simple VLOOKUP formula.

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A1:B20,2,FALSE)
```

where A2 is the value on Sheet 1 you want to look up, and A1:B20 is the entire table on Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF((F2=""),G2,F2)
```

This means: if cell `F2` is blank, return `G2`, else return the value of `F2`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a simple IF formula instead.

In cell B1 enter:

```
=IF(sheet1!$A1=sheet2!$A1,$A1)
```

and copy down as far as you need to go.